# Como solucionar el error de : FALLO: la compilación falló con una excepción. flutter.gradle 'línea: 904

Tags: flutter

He intentado con flutter clean, pub y aun no se resuelve, tambien volvi a descargar la carpeta del SDK de flutter en el  mismo lugar

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11m 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde android studio puedes actualizar a androidx.

Abres solo el proyecto android, Refactor >>> migrate to AndroidX,

algunas dependencias lo necesitan.

o en el proyecto android >>> android >> gradle >> wrapper >> gradle-wrapper.properties  cambias por esta linea-->>>

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip

pero no se recomienda